# Put filter on list column using XSL

Tags: xslt, xslt-list-view-web-part

I want to customize the design of the web part using XSL. But when I apply the XSL file in XSL Link(Miscellaneous) during Edit Page the default behavior of filter disappears. How can I do this in XSL file.